# Jasypt with the Bouncy Castle JCE SHA512 encryption

Tags: encryption, bouncycastle, jce, sha512, jasypt

I need: 
**password based encryption using sha512 digesting and 256 bit AES encryption with cbc and bc flags set**.

Seems that algorithm should be like this: **PBEWithSHA512AndAES256-CBC-BC**

but in my local env I get error: *org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: PBEWithSHA512AndAES256-CBC-BC for provider BC*

my test code:

```
import java.security.Security;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor;

public class App {

static {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StandardPBEStringEncryptor mySecondEncryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
    mySecondEncryptor.setProviderName("BC");
    // mySecondEncryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC");
    mySecondEncryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithSHA512AndAES256-CBC-BC");
    mySecondEncryptor.setPassword("pass");

    String myText = "Mindaugas";
    String mySecondEncryptedText = mySecondEncryptor.encrypt(myText);

    System.out.println(mySecondEncryptedText);
    System.out.println(mySecondEncryptor.decrypt(mySecondEncryptedText));
}
}
```

PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC - this algorithm works fine but I need sha512 and 256 bit AES...

I have installed extensions form: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

but still get this error: **no such algorithm**

Comment: May be, can somebody suggest better way how to achieve my goal (sha512 and 256 bit AES with cbc bc flags)?

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the extension into the correct JRE? If you have installed the JDK you have two JREs installed and I recommend you to install the extension into both of them.

Comment: yes, installed in Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\security and \Java\jre7\lib\security in case...

Comment: Are you sure that the algorithm name is correct? Alternatively I would try to use mySecondEncryptor.setConfig(...) for specifying the algorithms you need.

Comment: Not sure 100% that algorithm name is correct... but I do not find how to configure encryptor for password based encryption using **sha512 digesting and 256 bit AES encryption with cbc and bc flags set** ...

Comment: Use the working algo-name and just replace the numbers? The name you used that does not work uses a different scheme.

Comment: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC - works but with 512 not works 512 name: PBEWITHSHA512AND256BITAES-CBC-BC - do not works...

Answer (score 4):

Since the list of algorithms on the [bouncycastle website](https://bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) is not updated, looking at the code in the constructor in the Java file [BouncyCastleProvider.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/136/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider.java), you can find an exhaustive list of algorithms which are supported by bcprov-jdk16. A small list (of the type of algorithms/functions you were looking for) supported is -

```
PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHA1AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHA1AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHA1AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHA-1AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHA-1AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHA-1AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHA-256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHA-256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
PBEWITHSHA-256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
```